# How to create a bootable usb for OS X on Windows?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, bootable-disk

i had erase all data from my macbook and know i need to create a usb bootable to reinstall the yosemite or another version.

I can't access to app store to download the OS. How i can download it and create a usb bootable on Windows?

Comment: Use [Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201314) No USB key required.

Comment: I already tried to use internet recovery but during the download, i got an error with the message to download it from app store

Answer (score 1):

**Did you tried Google ?**

https://www.google.fr/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=How+to+create+a+bootable+usb+for+OS+X+on+Windows+%3F+-+Ask+Different&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ovcpVvzQFYex8weYkpKQDQ

---

Use [TransMac](http://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm), which has a 15-day trial period and works flawlessly.

1. In the left pane, right click the USB Drive and select **Restore with Disk Image**
2. Point to your .dmg file and click Open.

[image]

It will take a few minutes depending on size of .dmg and speed of USB drive, but once done you can pop it into your mac, hold down the option key when turning on the mac and choose the USB drive.

https://superuser.com/questions/383235/create-a-bootable-usb-drive-from-a-dmg-file-on-windows

Comment: I tried google of course. My main problem is to obtain dmg file without access to app store. Where i can download a valid dmg??

Comment: To get a clean and official dmg, you have to download it from the AppStore or from the Apple Developers center.

Comment: Great asnwer! Wihout OS, how do you download it from app store?

Comment: Mmmmm, you can't :/ Be careful, if you want to download El Capitan from the web, the most of them are infected.

Answer (score 0):

What operating system do you want?
If it is the OSX that was on your system you can do following easier:
Restart in the RecoveryPartition, click your language, then choose Install OSX.
And OSX will be installed on your system.
I assume that it is Yosemite afterwards.
Then decide if you want to upgrade, do it from the Appstore, or stay. 
If you want to have a bootable stick later on:
Download DiskMakerX and make a bootable stick with it.

Comment: Maybe i had deleted recovery partition when erase all data from my computer. When i start OS holding Alt Key, i dont see the icon of recovery. My last solution is donwload a valid dmg and write into usb pen.

Comment: @VítorNóbrega maybe it's time to contact Apple support... Maybe the tech guys at a physical Apple store or service center can reload the machine from a disk image.